# Алгоритм подсчёта комбинаций

Tags: алгоритм

есть 2 числа int обозначающих число объектов множества 1 и 2. например, countobj(1,3) означает что есть объекты 1.1 множества 1, и 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 множества 2. Нужно посчитать число возможных комбинаций из 3-х объектов, где есть хотя бы по одному объекту из каждого множества.
Например для набора чисел 1 и 3 ответ будет 3 ( это комбинации (1.1 2.1 2.2), (1.1 2.2 2.3), (1.1 2.1 2.2))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первым элементом результирующего множества будет один из элементов первого множества, оставшиеся 2 - сочетания по два элемента из второго множества, или наоборот.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где `n` и `m` - размеры множеств.

Answer (score 0):

Делим заданное общее количество на слагаемые в заданных пределах.

В примере - число 3 (всего объектов в варианте) делим на 2 (число множеств объектов) слагаемых, причём первое слагаемое находится в диапазоне от 1 (обязателен хотя бы 1 объект) до 1 (1 объект во множестве 1), а второе первое слагаемое находится в диапазоне от 1 (обязателен хотя бы 1 объект) до 3 (3 объекта во множестве 2).

Разбиение единственное = 1 + 2.

Для первого множества результат = С(1, 1) = 1.

Для второго множества результат = С(3, 2) = 3! / (2! * 1!) = 3.

Ответ = 1 * 3 = 3.

Если разбиений на слагаемые несколько - результат считается для каждого, и результаты суммируются.